# Column Alias name not considered by Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I tried run below HQL. Though I have specified alias name for columns, hibernate didn’t consider that.

**Here is the HQL:**

```sql
SELECT et1.entitlementId as A, et1.admTCId as B, 
          et1.barCode as C,et1.inactiveDate as D,
          et1.isEEntitlement as E,et1.magStripNumber as F,
          et1.serialNumber as G,et1.ticketBankInd as H 
FROM com.wdw.resmanagement.data.entity.AdmissionComponentEntitlement et1 
WHERE et1.inactiveDate IS NULL AND et1.serialNumber = :serialNumber
```

**Corresponding SQL generated By Hibernate:**

```sql
select
    admissionc0_.adm_enttl_id as col_0_0_,
    admissionc0_.adm_tc_id as col_1_0_,
    admissionc0_.brcd_vl as col_2_0_,
    admissionc0_.adm_enttl_inactv_dt as col_3_0_,
    admissionc0_.e_enttl_in as col_4_0_,
    admissionc0_.mag_strp_vl as col_5_0_,
    admissionc0_.serial_nb_vl as col_6_0_,
    admissionc0_.tkt_bank_in as col_7_0_ 
from
    RES_MGMT.adm_cmpnt_enttl admissionc0_ 
where
    (
        admissionc0_.adm_enttl_inactv_dt is null
    ) 
    and admissionc0_.serial_nb_vl=?
```

I am using Oracle 10g Database.

Can anybody know what should I change to get the same alias name in SQL (which hibernate is generating) ?

Comment: That query would return a `List<Object[]>`. What would you use the aliases for anyway? There's no way to use an alias to access an element of an array.

Comment: Expected SQL should be: select
    admissionc0_.adm_enttl_id as A,
    admissionc0_.adm_tc_id as B,
    admissionc0_.brcd_vl as C,
    admissionc0_.adm_enttl_inactv_dt as D,
    admissionc0_.e_enttl_in as E,
    admissionc0_.mag_strp_vl as F,
    admissionc0_.serial_nb_vl as G,
    admissionc0_.tkt_bank_in as H 
from
    RES_MGMT.adm_cmpnt_enttl admissionc0_ 
where
    (
        admissionc0_.adm_enttl_inactv_dt is null
    ) 
    and admissionc0_.serial_nb_vl=?

Comment: As hibernate is generating diff alias names for columns, it is affecting Database performance.

Comment: HQL != SQL. For executing SQL queries, use `createNativeQuery()`

Comment: i can only see the alias name being of relevance IF you also specified a result class. In the case of a result class, the JPA provider could use the alias names to match up to fields/properties of the result class (assuming it is of Java Bean type). I know the JPA provider I use supports that mode, but no idea on Hibernate - do you specify a result class?

Comment: You tagged [jpa]. Use JPQL and/or JPA criteria instead. Statements will then be portable across different providers with a little or no modification at all.